# NoClassDefFoundError: sun/misc/VM from ehcache, On migrating to java 9 during runtime

Tags: migration, ehcache, java-9

I am using ehcache-core-ee-2.6.11.jar and ehcache-terracotta-ee-2.6.11.jar and getting the following exception:
Also tried vm options: --add-modules jdk.unsupported but not working.

```
Caused by: net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/misc/VM
at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.init(CacheManager.java:401)
at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.<init>(CacheManager.java:259)
at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.newInstance(CacheManager.java:1037)
at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.newInstance(CacheManager.java:818)
at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.create(CacheManager.java:799)
at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.getInstance(CacheManager.java:833)
at com.softwareag.ecp.cache.EhcacheEngine.<init>(EhcacheEngine.java:67)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:142)
... 61 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/misc/VM
at org.terracotta.ehcachedx.util.Vm.maxDirectMemory(Vm.java:195)
at org.terracotta.license.ehcache.LicenseManager.verifyOffHeapUsage(LicenseManager.java:148)
at net.sf.ehcache.EnterpriseFeaturesManager.createStore(EnterpriseFeaturesManager.java:117)
at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.initialise(Cache.java:1103)
at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.initializeEhcache(CacheManager.java:1306)
at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.addCacheNoCheck(CacheManager.java:1337)
at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.addConfiguredCaches(CacheManager.java:758)
at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.doInit(CacheManager.java:459)
at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.init(CacheManager.java:377)
... 72 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.misc.VM
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1285)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
... 81 more
```

Comment: sun.misc.VM was a unsupported/undocumented/JDK-internal class in previous releases. It has moved in JDK 9 (internal classes can be refactored/removed at any time). So best to submit a bug to ehcache, they should not be directly using this class.

Comment: Thank you. But just out of curiosity the hack of providing --add-modules jdk.unsupported should have worked. Why is it not working as expected? Did I miss something?

Comment: The jdk.unsupported module is resolved by default when compiling or running code on the class path, so `--add-modules jdk.unsupported` is a no-op. The issue is that ehcache is making use of an undocumented internal class that no longer exists (because it has moved to a different package). The maintainers of ehcache need to fix their code.

Comment: Thanks @AlanBateman

Answer (score 0):

Version 2.6.11 is really old. An newest version might work. Also, you seem to use Enterprise features. You should check with the appropriate support about how to tackle Java 9.